# Testing framework for ASP.Net modules + Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, functional-testing

I inherited a large framework (my employer purchased a product) that uses ASP.Net modules (.ascx files loaded dynamically by Default.aspx).  The product did not, of course, come with its tests (at least, I assume the product has tests).

Because the ASP.Net postback client-side experience is awful, I've started adding more modern, Javascript-heavy functionality both to the existing modules, and in the new ones I create.  Due to how the system works I really cannot move away from the module-driven framework currently in place into an MVC setup.

I'm looking for a test framework that can access both the browser and the back-end framework.  I think I've come up with a set of requirements for this framework/combination of frameworks:

1. MUST handle navigation to multiple pages (wizard-like behavior).
2. MUST handle new window popups.
3. MUST handle DOM manipulation via Javascript (showing/hiding elements).
4. MUST emulate mouse/keyboard input on pages.
5. MUST be able to query/validate Javascript variable states.
6. MUST be able to query/validate back-end SQL Server.
7. MAY be able to query/validate back-end ASP.Net state. (Nice to have.)

Ideally it would have integration with VS's Test Explorer, but that's not a hard-and-fast requirement.

Does such a framework exist?  The google searching I've done has come up with plenty for single-page Javascript-driven sites, MVC sites, and plain ASP.Net sites without pretty Javascript, but I've had a hard time finding (or recognizing) a framework to fit my needs.

Comment: Search for tools/libraries is off-topic on SO. Side note: ASP.Net modules mean something different... ascx are usually user controls, not modules.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Gotchya.  The system I'm using loads .ascx files and calls them modules.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Next time I need to ask a question like this, which SE site should I use?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com may be good place. Your question seem to have reasonable cafeterias, so probably would be on-topic there. Make sure to read tour/what-not-to-ask before posting (I don't visit that site enough to know if indeed the question fits there).